# How to retrieve hashtaged tweets from a list of users and post to Wordpress

Tags: plugins, twitter

Is there any way retrieving all the tweets from a list of profiles which are tagged with certain #hashtag using Twitter API 1.1 and applying it as a feed to Wordpress?

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105663/how-to-retrieve-hashtaged-tweets-from-a-list-of-users) but I'm not able to get this to work with Wordpress.

Thanks

Comment: Recommendation of plugins or themes or anything such is beyond the scope of this community. Please check http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. Now please edit the question accordingly for seeking help from the community.

Comment: OK, changed that to regular question